# Is there any API to fetch the verification status as per the number into TWILIO

Tags: twilio-api

I am new to Twilio Services, I just wanted to if there is any api to fetch the verfication status as per the phone number

I have gone through the doc for this, I found this : https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/v1/verification

Comment: I found the API but it is not working : 

Request: https://preview.twilio.com/Numbers/ActiveNumbers

Response :  
{
    "code": 20404,
    "message": "The requested resource /Numbers/ActiveNumbers was not found",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404",
    "status": 404
}

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean with the "verification status of a number". Best, you also describe the scenario in which you want to use it. I'm asking because the Verify service might not be the right think. Similarly, the "preview" endpoint is probably als not the right endpoint for you.